# Color coding data based off another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a main sheet with names along the side, and authorized equipment along the top.  I have separate sheets for each individual with all their assigned equipment.  How can I make the corresponding name/authorized equipment box change color depending on if they have the equipment on the other sheet or not.  For example, I have Smith who is authorized B13907 on the first sheet.  On a separate sheet, there is a list of all his equipment, one of which being B13907. What formula will allow the box to automatically change to green?

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know how your data is structured. Until then, I'm assuming:

- Your first sheet is called Main, agent names are in column A and equipment is in row 1.
- Your second sheet is called Assigned, agent names are in column A and assigned equipment is in columns B through F.

The function you can use in your Main sheet to check if the equipment in column B has been assigned to the agent in row 2, goes into cell Main!B2. The formula for this, would be:

```
=IFNA(MATCH(B$1,OFFSET(Assigned!$B$1:$F$1,MATCH($A2,Assigned!$A:$A,0)-1,0),0),"")
```

This returns the position of all assigned equipment as a numerical value.